# In SQL Server, how to obtain set of latest entries for an every set of parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like

```
 TIMESTAMP PARAMETER1 PARAMETER2 VALUE
 --------------------------------------
 111       2          3          12.00
 222       2          3          13.00
 333       2          3          13.00
 111       3          4          15.00
 222       3          4          19.00
 010       3          5          20.00
```

In SQL Server, I would need to build a query that would return several rows, one row per combination of PARAMETER1 and PARAMETER2, and only for latest timestamp that appears for the respective combination.

For the example above, for combination {PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2} = {2,3} the latest timestamp is 333, for {3,4} it is 222, and for {3,5} it is 010, so I'd like to write a query that returns:

```
 TIMESTAMP PARAMETER1 PARAMETER2 VALUE
 --------------------------------------
 333       2          3          13.00
 222       3          4          19.00
 010       3          5          20.00
```

Comment: I'd use a group by on the two parameters and a max on the timestamp then a sub-select to get the value. SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS LatestTimeStamp, PARAMETER1
, PARAMETER2, val.VALUE FROM ... AS samp LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM dbo.sample) AS val ON samp.LatestTimeStamp = val.TIMESTAMP AND samp.PARAMETER1 = val.PARAMETER1
AND samp.PARAMETER2 = val.PARAMETER2
GROUP BY PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2

Comment: Unfortunately, I disagree with the accepted answer on that question, so I've added what I think is a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I though do not believe the question needs down-vote, as the question is valid despite being a dublicate, and I do receive different answers.

Comment: I agree that a downvote to this was a bit harsh. But one of the reasons for a downvote is a lack of research and this has been asked so many times that isn't a big stretch.

Comment: @Adam you should post that as an answer instead of a comment. Not only would you likely get rep if it is a good answer it would be legible. Comments are just hideous for code.

Comment: I would but someone marked it as a dup so a comment was all I could add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked and answered hundreds if not thousands of times. But it was easier to type out an answer than find a duplicate.

```
select TIMESTAMP
    , PARAMETER1
    , PARAMETER2
    , VALUE
from
(
    select TIMESTAMP
        , PARAMETER1
        , PARAMETER2
        , VALUE
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PARAMETER1, PARAMETER2 order by TIMESTAMP desc)
)x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: LOL...found a duplicate before you typed out the answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman well shoot I guess you proved me wrong. :)